# Too Many Semaphores in the Unisex Bathroom Problem?

Tags: python, concurrency, semaphore

I'm coding a solution to the Unisex bath problem using semaphores in Python.

For those who don't know, this problem states the following:

> In an office there's a new bath. This bath can be accessed by both man and woman but both genders can't access it at the same time. Moreover, this bathroom can only hold up to 3 employees.

There are more requisites added to increase the difficulty: there can not be starvation, two multiplex semaphores must be used (one per gender), when you access the bath you must print the name of the person who entered, how many times has accessed the bath and how many people is inside at the moment and you must signal when the bath is empty.

This is my code so far:

```py
    import threading
    import time
    import random

    # Constants
    FEMALE_NAMES = ["ADA", "BEA", "CALI", "DIA", "EMA", "FAY"]
    MALE_NAMES = ["ACE", "BEN", "CID", "DAN", "EDD", "FEZ"]
    N_ITERATIONS = 2
    N_FEMALE = 6
    N_MALE = 6
    DELAY = 0.01

    # Variables
    fem_counter = 0
    male_counter = 0
    using_bath = 0

    # Semaphores 
    mutex = threading.Semaphore()
    turnstile = threading.Semaphore()
    empty = threading.Semaphore()
    maleSwitch = threading.Semaphore()
    femaleSwitch = threading.Semaphore()
    maleBathMultiplex = threading.Semaphore(3)
    femaleBathMultiplex = threading.Semaphore(3)

    class Human(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self, name):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.id = name
            self.bathTimes = 0

        def arrive(self):
            print("{} arrives to work".format(self.id))

        def work(self):
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,9)*DELAY)
            print("{} works".format(self.id))

        def exitWork(self):
            print("{} goes home".format(self.id))
        
        def useBath(self):
            print("{}".format(id))
            self.bathTimes += 1

        def run(self):
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,9)*DELAY)
            self.arrive()
            while self.bathTimes < N_ITERATIONS:
                self.work()
                time.sleep(random.randint(1,9)*DELAY)
                self.useBath()
            self.exitWork()

    class Woman(Human):
        def useBath(self):
            global fem_counter
            global using_bath

            #Get turn
            turnstile.acquire()

            #Check or set bath gender
            femaleSwitch.acquire()
            fem_counter += 1
            if fem_counter == 1:
                empty.acquire()
            femaleSwitch.release()
            turnstile.release()

            #Access bathroom
            femaleBathMultiplex.acquire()

            # Increase counters and print bath status
            mutex.acquire()
            using_bath += 1
            self.bathTimes += 1
            print("\t{} Enters {}/2. Females inside: {}/3".format(self.id, self.bathTimes, using_bath))
            mutex.release()

            # "Use" bath
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,9)*DELAY)

            # Decrease counters
            mutex.acquire()
            using_bath -= 1
            mutex.release()

            print("{} exits".format(self.id))

            femaleBathMultiplex.release()

            # End turn
            femaleSwitch.acquire
            fem_counter -= 1
            if fem_counter == 0:
                print("*** Empty bath ***")
                empty.release()
            femaleSwitch.release()


    class Men(Human):
        def useBath(self):
            global male_counter
            global using_bath
            
            # Get turn
            turnstile.acquire()

            # Check or set bath gender
            maleSwitch.acquire()
            male_counter += 1
            if male_counter == 1:
                empty.acquire()
            maleSwitch.release()
            turnstile.release()

            # Access bathroom
            maleBathMultiplex.acquire()
            
            # Increase counters and print bath status
            mutex.acquire()
            using_bath += 1
            self.bathTimes += 1
            print("{} enters {}/2. Males inside: {}/3".format(self.id, self.bathTimes, using_bath))
            mutex.release()

            # "Use" bath
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,9)*DELAY)

            # Decrease counters
            mutex.acquire()
            using_bath -= 1
            mutex.release()

            print("{} exits".format(self.id))
            
            maleBathMultiplex.release()

            # End turn
            maleSwitch.acquire
            male_counter -= 1
            if male_counter == 0:
                print("*** Empty bath ***")
                empty.release()
            maleSwitch.release()

    def main():
        # Process preparation
        employees = []
        for i in range(N_MALE):
            employees.append(Men(MALE_NAMES[i]))
        for i in range(N_FEMALE):
            employees.append(Woman(FEMALE_NAMES[i]))

        # Start
        for e in employees:
            e.start()
        
        # Wait
        for e in employees:
            e.join()

        # The end
        print("DONE")
        

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

As you can see I used light switches and a turnstile besides the multiplexes to control the access to the bath and a mutex to control the message printing.

In total, I've used 7 semaphores but isn't this number to high? I'm not sure if this is normal as I'm quite new to the concurrency world.

Comment: This is a problem that is much more suited to a condition variable rather than semaphores, and implementing it with semphores essentially comes down to "how do I emulate a condition var with semphores"

Comment: Point of style: The methods and attributes of your `Woman` class and your `Men` class are virtually the same except for which global variables they use. An important principle of good software engineering is, "[Keep it DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)." Imagine if your teacher said, "It turns out that two genders is not enough. Change your code to work with any number of mutually-exclusive genders, and have it read the names of them from a config file at startup." That's a kind of thing that actually happens when you are designing software for the real world.

Comment: I would implement a Bathroom class, the incorporates an occupied semaphore, and a  number_of_occupants attribute as well as a occupancy_gender attribute..  As indicated by @SolomonSlow I would create a second Human Class with a type attribute being either Male or Female